VSC use different node for tsserver
Can anyone tell me that something is wrong with vsc and tsserver?
I use nvm, and my project node is v16, vsc uses tsserver.js from my project directory:
2024-05-16 19:23:41.622 [info] Using tsserver from: /Users/username/Documents/Projects/ProjectName/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js

It uses different node versions to run this server:
2024-05-16 19:23:41.622 [info] Using Node installation from /Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.13.1/bin/node to run TS Server

this lts version is set as the default alias.
